On unity, android platform, firebase doesn't select app at runtime by package name
on firebase dashboard, I create 2 android app in a project. I download google-services.json and it contains 2 app with 2 different package name. I build 2 apk with those 2 package name and log
Debug.LogError(FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Options.AppId);
when I run, I see that 2 apk show the same appID. How firebase select app in runtime? I thought it must rely on android package name.

Do both games access the same apps resources? Does EDM4U create any dialogues mentioning package name mismatch? Look through your Logs and see if this mismatch is mentioned there as well.
